how can I solve this gradle related error?
I am facing this error while running the program on VS Code
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
